# Error in Spring Boot application failed to convert from one type to another

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Currently I am creating a Spring Boot application and getting this error

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).Failed to convert from type [java.util.ArrayList<?>] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query java.util.List<com.example.vismameetingappwithdb.entity.Meeting>] for value '[Jono Java Meetingas]'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query com.example.vismameetingappwithdb.entity.Meeting]
```

My repository interface looks like this:

```
@ Repository
public interface MeetingRepository extends JpaRepository<Meeting,Integer>{

@ Query("SELECT nameOfMeeting FROM Meeting WHERE responsiblePerson =?1 ")
List<Meeting> findAllByResponsiblePerson(String responsiblePerson);
}
```

My RestController class looks like this:

```
@ RestController
public class MeetingController {

private MeetingService meetingService;

@ Autowired
public MeetingController(MeetingService meetingService){
this.meetingService = meetingService;
}

@ GetMapping("/getmeetings")
public List<Meeting> findAll (){
return meetingService.findAll();
}

@ GetMapping("/responsibleperson/{responsiblePerson}")
public List<Meeting> findAllByResponsiblePerson(@PathVariable String responsiblePerson) {
return meetingService.findAllByResponsiblePerson(responsiblePerson);
}
}
```

Has anyone encountered such problem before? Can anyone help? I am trying to use responsibleperson endpoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Focus at your code

```
@ Query("SELECT nameOfMeeting FROM Meeting WHERE responsiblePerson =?1 ")
List<Meeting> findAllByResponsiblePerson(String responsiblePerson);
}
```

- SQL query get list of `nameOfMeeting`, it is `List<String>`.
- Method returns list of `Meeting`, it is `List<Meeting>`.

Thefore the mismatching causes error.